# Passing -p:FrameworkPathOverride to MSBuild step in Hudson

Tags: .net, msbuild, hudson, c#-6.0, .net-4.6

I'm trying to setup a build item on a Hudson continuous integration server using the MSBuild step.

These are the parameters I'm passing:

```
-p:FrameworkPathOverride="C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6" /p:Configuration=Release
```

While this works when I run it from a console, it fails in Hudson:

```
Path To MSBuild.exe: C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe
Executing the command cmd.exe /C "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe" "-p:FrameworkPathOverride=C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6" /p:Configuration=Release C:\Projects\MyProject\MyProject.sln && exit %%ERRORLEVEL%% from C:\Projects\MyProject
[NET-Examino] $ cmd.exe /C "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe" "-p:FrameworkPathOverride=C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.6" /p:Configuration=Release C:\Projects\MyProject\MyProject.sln && exit %%ERRORLEVEL%%
'C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
[DEBUG] Skipping watched dependency update for build: MyProject Countinuous Build #27 due to result: FAILURE
Finished: FAILURE
```

How can I solve this without using the "Execute Windows batch command" step?

Comment: Put extra quotes around that command cause hudson (I think) seems to remove them?

Comment: I already tried all single quote/double quote combinations I could think of. Hudson seems very determined to remove them and put its own around the parameter...

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your parameter is not specified correctly. It should be `/p:`, but you have `-p:`.